# How to specify timeout for a particular request in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I specify timeout of 2 minutes for a particular request in rails application. One of my application request is taking morethan 5 minutes in some cases. In that case I would like to stop processing that request if it is taking morethan 2 mins.

I need this configuration at application level so that in future if there are any other such type of requests I should not do any special changes otherthan mentioning that action in that configuration. There are some requests which take morethan 10mins also. But they should not have any effect.

Thanks,

Comment: maybe [Timeout](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html) can help?

Comment: Your requests should never take that long. Do the work in the background process and inform the user that the content is not ready if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the timeout for a request back that far is generally bad practice. Making your users wait for minutes on end for a request to finish isn't a good idea.

Instead, this type of long-running task should be placed into a job queue for a worker process to run at it's convenience independent of the web request. This

- allows the web request to finish very quickly, making your user happy
- the long-running task to stay out of your web process, freeing it up to do what its supposed to (serve web requests)

Consider a gem like **[delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)**. Describing how to work it into your application is outside of the scope of this question; my answer here serves only to point out that looking to modify the timeout is very likely the wrong 'answer' and than you're better off looking at a job queue.